# How to get the conditionally calculated value in useEffect to reflect before rendering?

Tags: html, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to make a simple game. To get started with, I am trying to make a html element move within bounds of its parent . With my solution the html element is moving correctly but at the end it moves a little beyond the right bound.

What is the issue here?

```
     import { useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useRef, useState } from "react"
     import './Snake.css'
    export default ()=>{

    const [count, setcount] = useState(0)

    const [arr, setArr] = useState([0])

    const ref= useRef(0)

    const childRef= useRef(0)

    
     useEffect(() => {

    let rightBound=ref.current.getBoundingClientRect().right

    let childRight=childRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().right

    console.log(totalWidth+" "+childWidth)

    let interval= setInterval(()=>{

        if(rightBound>=childRight)
        setcount(count+100)
    else
    setcount(0)

    },1000)

    return () => {

    clearInterval(interval)
    
    }
     }, [count])

   
    

      return(
      <div className="parent" ref={ref}>

       <div className="snakeContainer" ref={childRef}  style={{left:count+"px"}}>


     {arr.map((value)=>{

     return(
        <div className="snakeboxes" key={value} ></div>
     )

     })}

     </div>

     </div>

    
     )


      }
```